# Vaadin CDI usage of pseudo scope vs normal scope annotations

Tags: java, vaadin, cdi

> This question is Vaadin specific (official vaadin-cdi add-on), also posted at Vaadin forum, https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/16829987

Vaadin CDI specific scopes (UI and View) come in two incarnations: as pseudo scope and as normal scope. 
These concepts are clear (for me) and "the why" is well explained in the awesome Vaadin documentation.

However, what is *not* clear for me and a cannot find an answer on these questions:

- Recommended is to use the pseudo scope variants. Because the normal scoped (and from CDI's point of view recommended) "have issues". What issues are we talking about? Are these issues resolvable or more structural? Is any help needed to get this resolved?
- If normal scope is not recommended, why do they exists? Having both is not consistent with "Fighting for Simplicity" :)
- Finally there is `VaadinSessionScoped`. Not mentioned in the documentation (https://vaadin.com/docs/framework/v8/advanced/advanced-cdi.html) and as far i understand redundant because we already have the standard SessionScoped. Or do i miss something?

Comment: What is the reason for a down vote? If something is wrong with this question, please leave a comment so i can improve it.